# Jar command not adding requested manifest file to archive

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I am running the following - and the resulting MANIFEST.MF does not contain the one referenced below:

```
jar -cvf instrument.jar -m instrument/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C instrument .
```

Here is the intended MANIFEST.MF:

```
18:23:20/shared $ll instrument/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  staff  33 Mar 31 17:57 instrument/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Here is the resulting jar file (notice incorrect date/size of MANIFEST.MF)

```
18:34:02/shared $jar -tvf instrument.jar
     0 Tue Mar 31 17:58:58 PDT 2015 META-INF/
    68 Tue Mar 31 17:58:58 PDT 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   544 Tue Mar 31 17:56:42 PDT 2015 ObjectSizeFetcher.cl
```

Here are contents of the intended manifest:

```
18:36:39/shared $cat instrument/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Premain-Class: ObjectSizeFetcher
```

Here are actual contents inside the jar file:

```
8:35:38/x2 $cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_25 (Oracle Corporation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to list all the options, except -C first, then the arguments (yeah, I know, original :)) and also provide the list of files to include

```
jar -cvfm instrument.jar instrument/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C instrument .
```

should do what you want.